# Cannot convert lambda expression to type "string" because it is not a delegate type?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
buyers.OrderBy(x => x.Visits.Where( y => y.VisitStart > date).Count());
```

In the orderby expression I get Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.
What the code is supposed to do is sort my "buyers" by number of "visits" they had in last 3 months.

`Buyers` is entity that has List of Visits and `Visit` has `DateTime VisitStart`

If it makes any difference,buyers is `IQueryable<Buyer>` and Visits is `ICollection<Visit>`

Comment: What is `buyers`? `Visits`? and `VisitStart`?

Comment: Sorry guys.Just edited

Comment: Are you sure that *this* code gives you error?

Comment: If it makes any difference,buyers is IQueryable and Visits is ICollection,probably does

Answer (score 1):

The actual code was

```
buyers.OrderBy(x => x.Visits.Where( y => y.VisitStart > date).Count() , sort.Direction);
```

problem was sort.Direction, but I was stupid and thought that it doesn't matter.
Sort is type of GridSortOptions and I was using it to sort some stuff manually.

Sorry about question,I left out the most important part obviously